# Как данное выражение правильно написать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Расставить точки над **«и»** или расставить точки над **«i»**

Comment: Алексей, на сайте принято отмечать все полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из ответов на свой вопрос галочкой как наиболее понравившийся и решивший проблему.

Answer (score 1):

**Корректно использовать второй вариант.*****расставить точки над «i»***Эта  идиома из французского языка проникла в русский, поскольку в русской дореформенной орфографии применяли букву **«i»**.

Это выражение  означает внести полную ясность, выяснить все умолчания, не оставить ничего недосказанным, довести до логического конца  ***Но доктор Кришнамурти сам решил расставить точки над «i».*** Л. М. Минц, «Дело вкуса», Ложкой, лепёшкой или просто рукой, 1995 г.  «Вокруг света»   ***Я сказал Оксане, что хочу объясниться и расставить точки над «i», чтобы не было недомолвок.*** Дмитрий Каралис, «Роман с героиней», 2001 г.  «Звезда»  ***Как Шкловский сумел ― хотя бы для себя ― расставить точки над «i» в таком деликатном и, по тогдашним меркам, тайном сюжете? Борис Парамонов, «Трава родины, или Сталь и шлак», 2003 г.***

Comment: Alexsey, правите выделения, тогда поправьте ещё в последнем примере (автор и название). А также первую строку: что-там не так со звёздочками и пробелами.

Answer (score 0):

**Вопрос № 286522**

Расставить точки над и или над i? Заранее спасибо.

Ответ **справочной службы** русского языка

**Возможны варианты**: расставить все точки над «i», расставить все точки над «и».

Примеры **[Карта слов](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5+%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4+%D0%B8)**

**[О значении фразеологизма](https://na-dostupnom.ru/rasstavit-vse-tochki-nad-i/)**